# Proving that the set is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W\subset \mathbb R^3$ is the set of all $(a,b,c)$ such that the system
$$x+2y+3z=a$$
$$4x+5y+6z=b$$
$$7x+8y+9z=c$$

is consistent. Prove that $W$ is the vector subspace of the vector space $\mathbb R^3$.

System is consistent if $rank(A)=rank(B)$ where
$$      A=  \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow rank(A)=2$$
and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & a\\
        4 & 5 & 6 & b\\
        7 & 8 & 9 & c\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$ 
$rank(B)=2$ if $a-2b+c=0$.

Now we need to show that $W$ is the vector subspace of the vector space $\mathbb R^3$.

$1.$ Closure of $W$ under addition

$$\forall x,y\in W,x+y\in W$$

$2.$ Closure of $W$ under scalar multiplication in $\mathbb R^3$
$$\forall x\in W,\forall\alpha\in\mathbb R^3, \alpha x\in W$$

How to prove these properties?

Comment: You have shown that $(a,b,c) \in W$ provided that $a-2b+c=0$. So assume $x=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $y=(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ are both in $W$. Can you show $x+y \in W$, i.e., $(a_1+a_2)-2(b_1+b_2)+(c_1+c_2)=0$? Similarly for showing $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @kccu, What is the actual procedure for showing that $(a_1+a_2)-2(b_1+b_2)+(c_1+c_2)=0$ and closure under scalar multiplication?

Comment: You know that $a_1-2b_1+c_1=0$ and $a_2-2b_2+c_2=0$ because $x,y \in W$. So you can actually compute the value of $(a_1+a_2)-2(b_1+b_2)+(c_1+c_2)$ by rearranging it.

Comment: @kccu, And what about the closure under scalar multiplication? We have $\alpha=(u,v,w),x=(a_1,b_1,c_1)\Rightarrow \alpha x=u(a_1+b_1+c_1)+v(a_1+b_1+c_1)+w(a_1+b_1+c_1)$. Is this correct? Now, how to show that $\alpha x\in W$?

Comment: Condition 2 is wrong: it should read $$\forall x\in W,\forall\alpha\in\mathbb R, \alpha x\in W$$

Comment: @N74 is correct. You should be multiplying each coordinate by one real number $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, not by a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So if $x=(a,b,c)$, then $\alpha x = (\alpha a, \alpha b, \alpha c)$.

Answer (score 1):

The system is consistent if and only if the vector $(a,b,c)$ is in the image of the map defined by your matrix $A$.  Therefore the set $W$ is precisely the image of that map.  But the map defined by a matrix is a linear map, and the image of a linear map is always a vector subspace.  Therefore the rank of $A$ is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that any linear combinations $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in W$ also admits to a solution that can be found easily and without using the rank-nullity theorem. If $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are consistent for the given system $A$, then
$$\underbrace{Ax}_{\vec{a}} + c\underbrace{Ay}_{\vec{b}} = \underbrace{A(x + cy)}_{\text{Consistent}} = \vec{a} + c\vec{b}$$
Where $c$ is some arbitrary scalar and $x + cy$ is the solution, so the subspace is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. Note that we assumed $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in W$, so it must be that $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ exists such that $Ax = \vec{a}$ and $Ay = \vec{b}$